# Angularjs custom headers with interceptors

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a custom header using interceptors to every request I make on the app and I get the following error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   httpRequestInterceptorProvider <- httpRequestInterceptor <- $http <-
>   $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

```
// Ionic Starter App
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var app = angular
            .module('app', ['ionic', 'auth0.lock', 'angular-jwt'])
            .config(config)
            .factory(factory)

    factory.$inject = ['httpRequestInterceptor'];
    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'lockProvider', 'jwtOptionsProvider', '$httpProvider'];

    function factory(httpRequestInterceptor) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers['X-switch-using'] = isApple;
                return config;
            }
        }
    }

    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, lockProvider, jwtOptionsProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
                .state('app', {
                    url: '/app',
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: 'components/menu/menu.html',
                })
                .state('app.home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('app.dashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard',
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: 'components/template/template.html'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('app.signin', {
                    url: '/login',
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: 'components/login/login.html'
                        }
                    }
                });

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');

        lockProvider.init({
            clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
            domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
            options: {
                auth: {
                    redirect: false,
                    params: {
                        scope: 'openid',
                        device: 'Mobile device'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Configuration for angular-jwt
        jwtOptionsProvider.config({
            tokenGetter: function () {
                return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
            },
            whiteListedDomains: ['localhost'],
            unauthenticatedRedirectPath: '/login'
        });
    }
})();
```

When I try to `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');`
Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 1

The first problem is that there is no dependency in your app like `httpRequestInterceptor`.

## Problem 2

The 2nd major problem is that you can not inject a simple factory or service in the config phase of Angular.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

> Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration
>   blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before
>   they have been fully configured.

So consider changing your code like this:

```
// Ionic Starter App
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var app = angular
            .module('app', ['ionic', 'auth0.lock', 'angular-jwt'])
            .config(config)
            //.factory(factory)             // Removed factory

    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'lockProvider', 'jwtOptionsProvider', '$httpProvider'];

    function factory() {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers['X-switch-using'] = isApple;
                return config;
            }
        }
    }

    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, lockProvider, jwtOptionsProvider, $httpProvider) {
        /** your state configuration here **/

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(factory);

        /** your lockprovider and jwtOptionsProvider here **/
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you Shashank Agrawal, you are a genius!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are inject interceptor here `factory.$inject = ['httpRequestInterceptor'];` but what exactly the `httpRequestInterceptor` is ? you have not create anything with that name.
What you need to do is change below functions name to `httpRequestInterceptor` from `factory`:

```
function factory(httpRequestInterceptor)
```

and make it `function httpRequestInterceptor()`

Then replace `.factory(factory)` with `.factory(httpRequestInterceptor)` and you can remove `factory.$inject` if you dont need to inject anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `factory` with `httpRequestInterceptor` which you are injecting in your `factory` named `factory`. If at all the factory `httpRequestInterceptor` is another module, you have inject that module as a dependency in your `app` module.

```
var app = angular
            .module('app', ['ionic', 'auth0.lock', 'angular-jwt','inject
                              the module which has the httpRequestInterceptor factory'])
            .config(config)
            .factory(factory)
```